# How to compile mysql56-client to USE_OLD_FUNCTIONS on FreeBSD 10?

Tags: mysql, freebsd

**EDIT: I solved my issue** - I was editing the wrong include file.  See the end of this post for the fix.

I'm migrating some applications from an old FreeBSD 4.3 server to a new FreeBSD 10 server.  These are C applications that use the MySQL C API.  They are very very old and use the `mysql_connect` function (which is deprecated in newer versions of MySQL).  From what I can gather looking at the MySQL source, the MySQL client API needs to be compiled with `USE_OLD_FUNCTIONS`.  Unfortunately I can't figure out how to do this.  I'm attempting to install MySQL 5.6 with the FreeBSD ports system.  I did the following, which I think should work:

```
cd /usr/ports/databases/mysql56-client
make fetch
make extract
make configure
```

I then edited `work/mysql-5.6.16/include/config.h` and added the following line at the very end:

```
#define USE_OLD_FUNCTIONS
```

Then I compiled and installed the client:

```
make
make install
```

`mysql_config` shows the following:

```
# mysql_config --libs
-L/usr/local/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient  -pthread -lm
# mysql_config --cflags
-I/usr/local/include/mysql -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -g -DNDEBUG
```

When I attempt to compile a very simple test client, shown below, I get a linker error that says `undefined reference to 'mysql_connect'`.  Test client code is as follows:

```
#define USE_OLD_FUNCTIONS
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
  MYSQL *sock;
  sock = mysql_connect(NULL, NULL, "root", "test");
  mysql_close(sock);
}
```

When I attempt to compile it, I get a linker error:

```
# clang -o test -I/usr/local/include/mysql -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -g -DNDEBUG test.c -L/usr/local/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient -pthread -lm
/tmp//ccTJC9Ov.o: In function `main':
/root/admin/test.c:8: undefined reference to `mysql_connect'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The following test program, which uses the newer `mysql_real_connect` function, compiles just fine with the same compiler arguments and runs without error:

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
  MYSQL *sock;
  sock = mysql_init(NULL);
  mysql_real_connect(sock, NULL, "root", "test", NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
  mysql_close(sock);
}
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?  The MySQL documentation for `USE_OLD_FUNCTIONS` seems to be nonexistent.  I can't blame them since these functions have been deprecated for a *long* time, but the code still seems to be there.

**Solution:**

I think I figured it out.  Instead of editing `work/mysql-5.6.16/include/config.h`, I should have edited `work/mysql-5.6.16/include/my_config.h`.  I added the following to the latter file, recompiled MySQL, and my test program compiles and links just fine now.

```
#define USE_OLD_FUNCTIONS
```

Note that I added this to `my_config.h` just before the last `#endif` in the file.  Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Could you please post that solution as an Answer below. Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisS - I tried, but it won't let me post an answer to my own question until 8 hours have passed.  I'll come back later and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  Instead of editing `work/mysql-5.6.16/include/config.h`, I should have edited `work/mysql-5.6.16/include/my_config.h`.  I added the following to the latter file, recompiled MySQL, and my test program compiles and links just fine now.

```
#define USE_OLD_FUNCTIONS
```

Note that I added this to `my_config.h` just before the last `#endif` in the file.  Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.